# How are related convolutional form to likelihood function?

Tags: functions

Is there any relationship between these forms, given a convolution method defined by integrated product functions $f, g$ as:

$\displaystyle (f*g)(x)=\int _{G}f(y)g\left(y^{-1}x\right)\,d\lambda (y)$

Could a likelihood function have a similiar approach on those methods and how is compared to convolution?

$argmax_{\theta}\digamma(\Theta|x\in[x_{j},x_{j}+h])=argmax_{\theta} \cfrac 1h \digamma(\Theta|x\in[x_{j},x_{j}+h])$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.